# Why images can not be seen in TImage on some devices?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I use TImage (in Delphi XE5, FMX) in my app.but all of the components can be seen except TImage content on some devices.
I try to display any pictures in bitmap or jpeg formats. I set bitmap in MultiResBitmap property in DesignTime or load jpeg image in Runtime.

For example on Device : **Samsung Galaxy S Dous2 Android 2.3.6 , HTC ONE M8 Android 4.4 , Huawei Tab 7 android 4.3 , Huawei P6 Android 4.2.2**  TImage Content can not be seen and Show a black rectangle. on other devices TImage worked properly.

Comment: What do you (want to) display in your TImage?

Comment: I use TImage to display any pictures in bitmap or jpeg formats. I set bitmap in MultiResBitmap property in DesignTime or load jpeg image in Runtime. anyway on some device TImage contents seen and on some device can not be seen!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should first make a multiresbitmap with the [Editor](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/MultiResBitmap_Editor)

And then load the [Multi-Resolution Bitmap](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Using_Multi-Resolution_Bitmaps)